# How to copy one hundred files from folder to folder?

Tags: python

I have one million files in one folder, I want to copy just one hundred files from them in another folder:

```
import os
import shutil

dir_src = ("/Big_Folder")
dir_dst = ("/Small_Folder")

for filename in os.listdir(dir_src):
    shutil.copy( dir_src + filename, dir_dst)
    print(filename)
```

This script copy for me all files, how to copy just 100000 files please?

Comment: And exactly which 100 files do you want to copy? Any 100? 100 oldest? 
 First 100 in alphabetic order of filenames? Something else?

Comment: I don't care which one , I just need one hundred files to make my tests, for example  the first files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply slice the list you want to iterate over:

```
for filename in os.listdir(dir_src)[:100]:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Indexing your list will allow you to perform actions on the nth (or i in this case) iteration.

```
import os
import shutil

dir_src = ("/Big_Folder")
dir_dst = ("/Small_Folder")

dirList = os.listdir(dir_src)
for i in range(len(dirList)):
  if i == 100:
    break
  shutil.copy(dir_src + dirList[i], dir_dst)
  print(filename)
```

Comment: It works but is not very idiomatic in Python: we almost never use  `for i in len(something)`, instead we use `for i, item in enumerate(something)` or just iterate over `something`.

Comment: @Paulo Scardine your way does look nicer. We wouldn't be using python if speed was the number 1 priority however I do try to write faster code where I can. `for i in range(len(...))` is much faster (unless I'm mistaken).   I used iPython `%timeit` on a 10,000 element array with a `pass` to compare the iteration time.  The best of 3 loop time on py3.6 for given hardware was 346uS for `range(len(...))` and 1130uS for the enumerate method. Perhaps this deserves a new post to better compare the two.